# Content security policy error while loading fonts

Tags: javascript, css, font-face, content-security-policy

I have a local folder called "fonts", containing **otf** fonts. And I define the font-families using the @font-face rule.

The problem is, **I am not getting the fonts loaded**, because this error shows in the Chrome console:

Refused to load the font 'data:font/opentype;base64,T1RUTwAMAIAAAwBAQ0ZGINEulzEAAA94AACBwUdQT1MGggFzAACRPAAAKuxHU1VCV7A5EAAAvCgAAApeT1MvMlhzMAgAAAEwAAAAYGNtYXB8/3N7AAAJFAAABkJoZWFkAfQ0RwAAAMwAAAA2aGhlYQeiBSYAAAEEAAAAJGhtdHhDg3HpAADGiAAACHhrZXJug42ekAAAzwAAAG6IbWF4cAIeUAAAAAEoAAAABm5hbWUW0pxRAAABkAAAB4Jwb3N0/7gAMgAAD1gAAAAgAAEAAAABAIMQhDPpXw889QADA+gAAAAAz37b1wAAAADPfxQX/5T+zgRLBCgAAAADAAIAAAAAAAAAAQAAA8D/EAAABGr/lP+NBEsAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh4AAFAAAh4AAAADAnwBdwAFAAQCigJYAAAASwKKAlgAAAFeADIBRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAv9AAABbAAAAAAAAAABIJ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src-https//fonts.gstatic.com https//fonts.googleapis.com".

This also happens with Firefox / Safari.

I added this to my index.html, just under the "title" tag, but not working either:

Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Comment: I masked the url's in the meta-tag in order to being able to post this question.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com font-src https://fonts.googleapis.com">

Comment: Is the index.html file being served with a Content-Security-Policy response header, or is the meta element the only thing setting the CSP policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the meta tag as follows to solve:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src data: https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com">
```

This will allow loading font resources via the data scheme.

For more info on Content Security Policy See: https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Hi @seb-cooper, thank you very much for your response. However, it is not working yet :-(

Comment: @user2634368  What error message exactly do you now get after you make that change to the meta element? This policy in the meta element should work if the meta element is the only thing setting a CSP policy. But it won’t work if the document is being served with a Content-Security-Policy response header that doesn’t allow data: as a source for font-src

Comment: Thank you Seb Cooper. This finally helped too to solve the issue.